# Appium, running two phones at once for user and agent

Tags: android, appium, robotframework

I have a situation where I need to run one browser as a client and another browser as an agent.  On desktop this is easy and we use the browser of choice for the user and phantom for the agent.

Using Appium and running on the Android emulator I am having problems trying to replicate the desktop setup.  I first tried to have the computer run the phantom and then run the Appium tests but I was getting told by Appium that it didn't recognize phantom.  I couldn't find a way to have phantom run on the desktop while still using Appium for the phone.

Next I thought I would just automate the agent side directly in Chrome on the phone to avoid the split between desktop and phone.  However, I still ran into problems as I can't seem to create new tabs in Chrome to switch to and even with running two different phones I can't switch between them.

We decided to use RobotFramework and AppiumLibrary to code this due to readability for possible end users of this automation.

These are the first keywords run:

```
*** Keywords ***
Specifying a Known Mobile Device
    API Login    regression    password
    sleep   10
    Agent Login
    Open Application    http://localhost:4723/wd/hub  platformName=Android  browserName=Chrome  platformVersion=7.1.1  deviceName=Nexus6P  app=com.android.chrome  automationName=appium  appPackage=com.android.browser  appActivity=com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main
    go to url    blahblah.com
    Check Availability Regression Flow HSSMobile
```

API login and Agent login are:

```
API Login
    [Arguments]     ${UN}    ${PW}
    Set Global Variable    ${ACCOUNTNAME}    ${UN}
    Set Global Variable    ${ACCOUNTPWD}     ${PW}
    Open Application    http://localhost:4725/wd/hub  platformName=Android  browserName=Chrome  platformVersion=7.1.1  deviceName=Pixel  app=com.android.chrome  automationName=appium  appPackage=com.android.browser  appActivity=com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main
    go to url    blahblahapi.com

Agent Login

    MobileLibrary.Wait Until Element Is Visible    ${USERNAME}    25
    MobileLibrary.Input Text    ${USERNAME}   ${ACCOUNTNAME}
    MobileLibrary.Input Text    ${PASSWORD}   ${ACCOUNTPWD}
    MobileLibrary.Click Element    ${LOGIN}
```

I imagine I am doing something wrong in the Open Application keyword but I'm not sure.  I am running two instances of Appium in the command line.

```
appium
```

and

```
appium -p 4725
```

Yet, everything runs on only one of the phones.

Comment: Welcome to one of the most annoying problems in Robot Framework: switching between tabs on the browser. I can barely pull it off with a keyword that looks for an image of the tab I want to switch to. You're probably just better off opening a new instance of the browser and switching between browser instances.

Comment: Well, that's what I'm trying to do.  I couldn't find anything about adding tabs so I went straight to running two instances.

Comment: Well, that's because there isn't anything about tabs that I'm aware of. It's on the list of problems I'm working on fixing.